# How to recall JQuery function for fields calculation after button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have this JQuery function which I use for some calculations in the form:

```
<script src="Script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {

         $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtLikPotra_1").ClientID%>').on('input', function () {
            var txtLikPotra_1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txtLikPotra_1").ClientID%>').value.replace('.', ''));
            var txtLikObav_1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txtLikObav_1").ClientID%>').value.replace('.', ''));
            var txtDnPokazaLik_1 = txtLikPotra_1 / txtLikObav_1;
            if (txtDnPokazaLik_1 === Infinity || isNaN(txtDnPokazaLik_1)) {
                txtDnPokazaLik_1 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtDnPokazaLik_1").ClientID%>').val("");
            }
            else {
               var commaDnPokazaLik_1 = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txtDnPokazaLik_1").ClientID%>');
               commaDnPokazaLik_1 = txtDnPokazaLik_1.toFixed(2);
               commaDnPokazaLik_1 = commaDnPokazaLik_1.replace('.', ',');
               txtDnPokazaLik_1 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtDnPokazaLik_1").ClientID%>').val(commaDnPokazaLik_1);
            }
         });

         $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtLikObav_1").ClientID%>').on('input', function () {
            var txtLikPotra_1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txtLikPotra_1").ClientID%>').value.replace('.', ''));
            var txtLikObav_1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txtLikObav_1").ClientID%>').value.replace('.', ''));
            var txtDnPokazaLik_1 = txtLikPotra_1 / txtLikObav_1;
            if (txtDnPokazaLik_1 === Infinity || isNaN(txtDnPokazaLik_1)) {
                txtDnPokazaLik_1 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtDnPokazaLik_1").ClientID%>').val("");
            }
            else {
                 var commaDnPokazaLik_1 = document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txtDnPokazaLik_1").ClientID%>');
                 commaDnPokazaLik_1 = txtDnPokazaLik_1.toFixed(2);
                 commaDnPokazaLik_1 = commaDnPokazaLik_1.replace('.', ',');
                 txtDnPokazaLik_1 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtDnPokazaLik_1").ClientID%>').val(commaDnPokazaLik_1);
            }
         });

    })
```

When I try on button to save data from the form I have some validations which are checking are the inputs of the data in correct form. After that validation all calculations from the fields disappear.

How can I refresh or call again this JQuery function each time on button click?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like that:

```
$(function () {
    myFunction();
  $("#button").click(function () {
    myFunction();
  });
});

function myFunction() {
//Your code here
}
```

Put all your code inside the function called myFunction.